# pdfHTML/iText 7: Print <table> start/end row count in <tfoot>

Tags: c#, html, css, itext, pdfhtml

For a project I'm currently writing a document generator that uses pdfHTML 3.0.3 and iText 7.1.14. The document contains a table showing 'items'. These item rows will probably never actually fit one page and will span many pages in most cases.

The first column of this table has an item number, it's possibly that there are missing item numbers (due to items being void).

I would like the table to show the first and last item number in the `<tfoot>` of the `<table>`, in a ideal solution this first and last item would be dynamically determined based on what is printed on the currently layed out page.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAe2Z.png (FROM should show the number 1, and TO should show the number 5).

It seems this is not possible with HTML and CSS alone as they do not support any counters that use the page as context (CSS counters seem to use global context, not page context).

I think it might be possible to write a renderer based on `TableRenderer`, but I do not know where to start. iText documentation does show examples of how to create your own renderer, but I can't seem to find examples that are related to this question.

Comment: See following : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/multi-step-input-forms-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will be in Java but porting to C# should be a matter of changing some method names to start with uppercase letters. I'll base my answer on the following HTML visual representation of a table:

[image: HTML visual representation]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
      border: solid 1px black;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="30%">
    <col width="70%">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Varius quam quisque id diam. Malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus. Odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl. Purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent. Mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id. Eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. At urna condimentum mattis pellentesque.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo. Sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at. Nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in. Nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla. Quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl. Elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam. Aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi. Scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in. At urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit. Eget egestas purus viverra accumsan. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas. Ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas. In massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Porttitor massa id neque aliquam. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut.

      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet. Nec nam aliquam sem et. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Elit sed vulputate mi sit. Scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo. Enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit. Massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam. Lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. A diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet. Vitae turpis massa sed elementum. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla. Purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit. Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla. Nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Est velit egestas dui id ornare. Vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed. At volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac. Facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean. Donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>Tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Senectus et netus et malesuada. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et. Ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum. Massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>In eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam. Hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac. Consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas. Morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Morbi tristique senectus et netus. Sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque. Luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Senectus et netus et malesuada. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et. Ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum. Massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna.

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec.

    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr><td colspan="2">from <span id="from">dummy</span> to <span id="to">dummy</span></td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that we are using `page-break-inside: avoid;` CSS declaration here in order for a cell not to be broken across pages (which would make it more difficult for us to determine the range to display in the footer).

Also note that we have a special construct in our `<tfoot>` element:

```
  <tfoot>
  <tr><td colspan="2">from <span id="from">dummy</span> to <span id="to">dummy</span></td></tr>
  </tfoot>
```

We marked the `<span>` placeholders which will be filled with the range numbers with our custom `id`s. If you don't have full control over the HTML you use for PDF generation then you can perform some preprocessing steps to inject the desired `<tfoot>` contents into your HTML.

We'll need to customize some rendering behavior in our HTML to PDF conversion, and the starting point is customizing the tag worker factory which is passed into `ConverterProperties`:

```
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.setTagWorkerFactory(new CustomTagWorkerFactory());
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(sourceHtml), new File(targetPDF), converterProperties);
```

In our tag worker factory we need custom processing for the above mentioned `<span>` placeholders as well as for the generic `<table>` element (note that if you have several tables in your HTML then you might want to differentiate which table you are dealing with in your tag worker and only add customization for the table where you need to add ranges in the footer).

```
private static final class CustomTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (tag.name().equals("span") && ("from".equals(tag.getAttribute("id")) || "to".equals(tag.getAttribute("id")))) {
            return new ElementCounterTagWorker(tag, context);
        } else if (tag.name().equals("table")) {
            return new CustomTableTagWorker(tag, context);
        }
        return super.getCustomTagWorker(tag, context);
    }
}
```

The custom table tag worker is pretty basic - it just sets a custom renderer to the table's footer (the renderer itself will be defined below):

```
private static class CustomTableTagWorker extends TableTagWorker {
    public CustomTableTagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
    }

    @Override
    public IPropertyContainer getElementResult() {
        IPropertyContainer table = super.getElementResult();
        ((Table)table).getFooter().setNextRenderer(new CustomTableFooterRenderer(((Table) table).getFooter()));
        return table;
    }
}
```

The tag worker for the `<span>` element is also aimed at defining custom renderers for our `<span>` placeholders, but the implementation is a bit more difficult due to how mapping from HTML elements to iText layout elements is performed. Note that we also save the type of the placeholder (from `id` attribute) to the custom renderer:

```
private static class ElementCounterTagWorker extends SpanTagWorker {
    private IElementNode element;
    public ElementCounterTagWorker(IElementNode element,
            ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Override
    public List<IPropertyContainer> getAllElements() {
        List<IPropertyContainer> elements = super.getAllElements();
        for (IPropertyContainer elem : elements) {
            if (elem instanceof Text) {
                ((Text) elem).setNextRenderer(new TextCounterRenderer((Text) elem, element.getAttribute("id")));
            }
        }
        return elements;
    }
}
```

Now the most interesting part is the renderer definitions for the table and our span placeholders. The idea is that during layout of the span element, that element registers itself within the table footer renderer (which is one of the parents in the chain). Then the table footer renderer will replace the contents of the span element just before drawing the contents, when the exact layout positions have been defined already.

Here is how the custom renderer for text within our `<span>` placeholders is defined (note you must override both `getNextRenderer()` and `createCopy()`:

```
private static class TextCounterRenderer extends TextRenderer {
    String type;

    public TextCounterRenderer(Text textElement, String type) {
        super(textElement);
        this.type = type;
    }

    protected TextCounterRenderer(TextCounterRenderer other) {
        super(other);
        this.type = other.type;
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
        IRenderer tableRenderer = parent;
        while (!(tableRenderer instanceof TableRenderer)) {
            tableRenderer = tableRenderer.getParent();
        }
        ((CustomTableFooterRenderer)tableRenderer).register(this, layoutContext);
        return super.layout(layoutContext);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new TextCounterRenderer((Text) getModelElement(), type);
    }

    @Override
    protected TextRenderer createCopy(GlyphLine gl, PdfFont font) {
        TextCounterRenderer copy = new TextCounterRenderer(this);
        copy.setProcessedGlyphLineAndFont(gl, font);
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Finally, the implementation of our table footer renderer. The idea is to keep track of all the registered text renderers (our placeholders for insertion of the ranges), and then just before we are about to draw the table footer, analyze the content of the table we are about to draw to find the ranges of the rows that will be drawn on this page and inject those ranges into our placeholders.

```
private static class CustomTableFooterRenderer extends TableRenderer {
    private Set<Pair<TextCounterRenderer, LayoutContext>> textCounters = new HashSet<>();

    public CustomTableFooterRenderer(Table modelElement) {
        super((Table)modelElement);
    }

    public CustomTableFooterRenderer(Table modelElement, RowRange rowRange) {
        super(modelElement, rowRange);
    }

    public void register(TextCounterRenderer renderer, LayoutContext context) {
        Pair<TextCounterRenderer, LayoutContext> textNode = new Pair<>(renderer, context);
        if (!textCounters.contains(textNode)) {
            textCounters.add(textNode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        for (Pair<TextCounterRenderer, LayoutContext> counter : textCounters) {
            IRenderer counterParent = counter.getKey().getParent();
            while (counterParent != null && counterParent != this) {
                counterParent = counterParent.getParent();
            }
            if (counterParent == this) {
                TableRenderer tableRenderer = (TableRenderer) this.getParent();
                int columnCount = 2;
                IRenderer firstRowFirstCellRenderer = tableRenderer.getChildRenderers().get(0);
                IRenderer lastRowFirstCellRenderer = tableRenderer.getChildRenderers().get(tableRenderer.getChildRenderers().size() - columnCount);
                if ("from".equals(((TextCounterRenderer)counter.getKey()).type)) {
                    counter.getKey().setText(firstRowFirstCellRenderer.toString());
                } else {
                    counter.getKey().setText(lastRowFirstCellRenderer.toString());
                }
                counter.getKey().layout(counter.getValue());
            }
        }
        super.draw(drawContext);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomTableFooterRenderer((Table) modelElement, rowRange);
    }
}
```

All in all, we get the following result in the PDF:

[image: page 1 result]

[image: page 2 result]

Please note that there is no 100% guarantee this solution will work with all future iText versions because it depends on some implementation details, but it should work with iText 7.1.15 line and it gives a good idea on where to look for generic layout customizations in iText, both for HTML to PDF conversion contexts and pure layout module usages.